# Architecture Setup and Database

Tags: database, architecture, apache-kafka, feed, graph-databases

I am trying to create a social app in which users can follow their friends and their personalised feed is real time as well. 
Question : Is Graph Database the best option to cater to such problem. What is the experience when the data reaches millions. Also, what is the right way to proceed for feeds, do we keep Kafka stream for each user? How do I start with the whole setup with respect to over engineering, a start point and the flow.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends 100% on how you use these technologies.

Neo4j (a graph database) can store fairly large amounts of data:

> A graph database with a quadrillion nodes? Such a monstrous entity is
>   beyond the scope of what technologist are trying to do now. But with
>   the latest release of the Neo4j database from Neo Technology, such a
>   graph is theoretically possible.
>
> There is effectively no limit to the sizes of graphs that people can
>   run with Neo4j 3.0, which was announced today, says Neo Vice President
>   of Products Philip Rathle.
>
> “Before Neo4j 3.0, graph sizes were limited to tens of billions of
>   records,” Rathle says. “Even though they may not have tens of billions
>   of data items to actually store in a graph, just having a ceiling made
>   them nervous.”
>
> By adopting dynamically sized pointers, Neo4j can now scale up to run
>   the biggest graph workloads that customers can throw at it. The
>   company expects some of its customers will begin to put that extra
>   capacity to use, for things such as crunching IoT data, identifying
>   fraud, and generating product recommendations.

Source: https://www.datanami.com/2016/04/26/neo4j-pushes-graph-db-limits-past-quadrillion-nodes/

Start with something simple, Neo4j sounds like a good starting point. Once you start hitting bottlenecks or scaling issues, then you can start looking at other solutions. It's very hard to predict where your bottlenecks will be without real-world data.

Realtime feeds at scale is hard to build, first define how realtime do you want it to be. Is 1 minute still considered realtime? Maybe 5 minutes?
The number you choose here will directly affect your technology choices.

Either way, more information is needed to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To start off, the realtime metric that I am taking is upto 5 minutes. Also, down the line, I would want to get the realtime as down as possible. However, that is not the priority list right now.